# Stacking of Raster Image and Compressing it in python

Tags: python, raster, gdal

I am trying to stacking my raster .tif file I have 12 .tif files but I also want to compress the output stacked file in python.

Here is my current working code for stacking file but after stacking the size of the file is very large

```
from osgeo import gdal
outvrt='/vsimen/Stacked.tif'
outtif='E:/Users/Compressed_files/Stacked.tif'
tifs=glob.glob('E:/Users/Compressed_files/*.tif')
outds=gdal.BuildVRT(outvrt,tifs,seperate=True)
outds=gdal.Translate(outtif,outds)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a [TranslateOptions](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#TranslateOptions) object to your `gdalTranslate` call, where you can add the relevant `creationOptions` for compression.

So as dummy code:

```
from osgeo import gdal

topts = gdal.TranslateOptions(creationOptions=['COMPRESS=LZW', 'PREDICTOR=2'])
outds=gdal.Translate(outtif,outds, options=topts)
```

Of course, the options can also be a string or array of strings - it's not mandatory to use the `TranslateOptions`.

Also, the compression setting used in the dummy code is just an example. To maximize your gain, you should select options that work with your data.

Here's a excerpt from the [documentation on available options for GeoTiffs](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#raster-gtiff):

> COMPRESS=JPEG/LZW/PACKBITS/DEFLATE/CCITTRLE/CCITTFAX3/CCITTFAX4/LZMA/ZSTD/LERC/LERC_DEFLATE/LERC_ZSTD/WEBP/NONE]:
>   Set the compression to use. JPEG should generally only be used with
>   Byte data (8 bit per channel). But starting with GDAL 1.7.0 and
>   provided that GDAL is built with internal libtiff and libjpeg, it is
>   possible to read and write TIFF files with 12bit JPEG compressed TIFF
>   files (seen as UInt16 bands with NBITS=12). See the “8 and 12 bit JPEG
>   in TIFF” wiki page for more details. The CCITT compression should only
>   be used with 1bit (NBITS=1) data. LZW, DEFLATE and ZSTD compressions
>   can be used with the PREDICTOR creation option. ZSTD is available
>   since GDAL 2.3 when using internal libtiff and if GDAL built against
>   libzstd >=1.0, or if built against external libtiff with zstd support.
>   LERC/LERC_DEFLATE/LERC_ZSTD are available since GDAL 2.4 when using
>   internal libtiff (and for LERC_ZSTD, see above mentioned conditions).
>   None is the default.
>
> NUM_THREADS=number_of_threads/ALL_CPUS: (From GDAL 2.1) Enable
>   multi-threaded compression by specifying the number of worker threads.
>   Worth for slow compressions such as DEFLATE or LZMA. Will be ignored
>   for JPEG. Default is compression in the main thread.
>
> PREDICTOR=[1/2/3]: Set the predictor for LZW, DEFLATE and ZSTD
>   compression. The default is 1 (no predictor), 2 is horizontal
>   differencing and 3 is floating point prediction.